# How can i create curve UIView/UIImageView not with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

How can i create an uiview which looks like this and also its subview get the same effect.
After searching in web i found it can be done by CALayer, but i do not have enough knowledge on this . Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: How]

Comment: I don't think you can using Quartz or UIKit. Of course you can build curved path using bezier path, but they only apply at what it has been draw and not subviews or sublayer.
Using quartz and CATransform3D you can achieve some sort of 3d perspective views.<br>
What you want to do is OpenGL duty.

Comment: with out open gl is it not posssible?

Comment: What's the issue with using an image view with some transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Upto my levels and my understanding I have done some coding that may helpful to you..
If not please ignore it..

1st Create a custom View from new file

Next, we need to change the class of the ViewController's view property  from UIView to our CustomView class.  Open MainStoryboard.storyboard and in the document outline click on View icon.  Then, open the identity inspector (option+command+3) and change to class name to CustomView.

then add this code in custom View

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  // Drawing code
  UIImage *imageRecipe =[UIImage imageNamed:@"statement_card_1.png"];
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,290, 200)];
  imgView.image = imageRecipe;
  [self addSubview:imgView];

  CGPoint secondPoint = CGPointZero;
  CGPoint point1 = CGPointZero;
  CGPoint initial = CGPointZero;

  UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

  initial = CGPointMake(30, 60);
  [aPath moveToPoint:initial];

  CGPoint point = CGPointMake(290, 60);
  CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(point.x/2, -10);

  [aPath addQuadCurveToPoint:point controlPoint:centerPoint];


  secondPoint = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(aPath.CGPath);

  [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(secondPoint.x, 200.0)];

  point1 = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(aPath.CGPath);

  CGPoint p = CGPointMake(initial.x,point1.y);
  CGPoint cp = CGPointMake(point1.x/2 ,point1.y/2 + 30);

  [aPath addQuadCurveToPoint:p controlPoint:cp];

 [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(initial.x, secondPoint.y)];
 [aPath closePath];

 [aPath stroke];

 CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 maskLayer.frame = imgView.bounds;
 maskLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;
 imgView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Comment: no its not working just draw a curve on imageview. and mask it. Thnx for reply

Answer (score 0):

won't happen without OpenGL or some other engine. you can't morph a CALayer that way. The basic idea of a layer is that it is a plane.

maybe fake it with an image and some rotated views or something?